# Is "the smallest open set containing zero" a well defined concept?

Tags: real-analysis

A function is said to be *continuous at zero* iff:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)} = f(0)$

Could this be the same as saying:

- Let $\Delta$ = *the smallest open set containing zero*
- $f(x) = f(0), \forall x \in \Delta$

Am I misunderstanding what a limit is, or are these two definitions equivalent?

Edit:  I've got a few responses saying that there is no such set as $\Delta$.  I agree.  However, it seems to me that the expression:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{f(x)} = f(0)$

is definitively claiming to evaluate $f$ at *some* unspecified value or values $x \neq 0$ but not claiming any particular values.  To be specific, for any particular value you could name, the claim that the limit exists does *not* claim it needs to evaluate f at that point.  So, what exactly is it claiming?

Comment: There is no such $\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, no smaller set exist (for a standard usage of smaller, at least). In terms of open sets, what you can say is that $f$ is continuous at $p$ if for every open set $V$ containing $f(0)$, there is an open set $U$ containing $0$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$. This allows you to take arbitrarily small intervals, in particular, which approximates your intuitive idea of taking the 'smallest' such set.

Many concepts in analysis, in particular, use this same thought process: defining notions by making sense of approximations up to arbitrary precision.

Comment: Cool!  So, perhaps something like: $\Delta \:= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})}$

Comment: That... will most likely still give the empty set for any reasonable definition of limit of sets. The point here is to be comfortable with arbitrary approximations: you will not be able to have a 'smaller' set, but given a fixed desired precision, you will have a small enough neighborhood in which things behave as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no smallest open set containing zero.

Any open set containing zero by definition contains an open interval containing zero and that interval contains a smaller open interval containing zero.

Comment: Okay, but then, precisely, what set is f required to be defined on, in order for it to be considered continuous at zero?

Comment: @Henry $f$ must be defined in a set $X$ that contains 0. Any such $X$ could serve as the domain of $f$. Whether it is continuous or not depends on the values that $f$ takes at points of $X$, of course.

Comment: @Mohammad The domain does not need to contain any open interval about 0, even if it contains 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as “the smallest open set containing $0$”. That's so because if $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ (I'm assuming that you're working in $\mathbb R$) and $0\in A$, then $A\supset(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, for some $\varepsilon>0$. If $A\varsupsetneq(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, take $A^\star=(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$; otherwise, take $A^\star=\left(-\frac\varepsilon2,\frac\varepsilon2\right)$. In each case, $A^\star$ is an open set containing $0$ and $A^\star\varsubsetneq A$.

Comment: Unless $A=\mathbb R$, or $A\subset (-2,-1)$, or ...

Comment: You want open *intervals* containing zero ...

Comment: I agree.  But, then, how do you understand the notion of a limit?  It seems that the limit operation is implicitly asserting such a set.  Where, besides zero, is f required to be defined in order for f to be considered continuous at zero?

Comment: @Mark "$f$ needs to be defined in the neighborhood of 0." Not necessarily.

Comment: @Andres E. Caicedo, you mean $0$ can also be an isolated point and then $f$ is continuous? Yes, that's right. But that's the less interesting case.

Comment: @Mark Not just that. $f$ could be defined only in the Cantor set and still be continuous at 0, for instance.

Comment: @Andres E.Caicedo, you are right, that makes sense. Or it can be defined only in rational numbers, right?

Comment: @Mark Yes. There are many other options as well.

Comment: My point is that the notion of $\Delta$ and $\lim$ are actually equivalent notions.  Perhaps, like Kronecker's Delta function, the notion of "the smallest open set containing zero" is still a useful abstract concept even if it doesn't exist.  Kind of like the notion of infinity.

Comment: @Henry No, not at all.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Can you be more specific?  Do you mean that $\Delta$ and lim are not at all equivalent notions, or that $\Delta$ is not a useful abstract concept?  Or something else?

Comment: @Henry Both, actually.

Comment: @HenryBigelow The notion of a "filter", and its use in general topology, might somewhat approach what you're trying to think of in terms of $\Delta$.  In this case, the relevant filter would be the neighborhood filter consisting of all neighborhoods of 0.

Comment: Perhaps there is some alternative definition of "continuity at a point" which is something like "constant in an infinitessimally small neighborhood around the point".  Or in any case, some limiting definition that involves neighborhoods, rather than individual point.  Any thoughts?